# Arduino digital pin mapping in C#

Tags: c#, arduino

I'm writing a C# application that is going to interact with an Arduino Mega 2560.
But I'm quite new using Arduino's board.

So my question is it possible to map the pins in the C# application in order to monitor the states of my digital inputs.

Example:

I make the Arduino setup like this

```
pinMode(22, INPUT)
(...)
pinMode(53, INPUT)
```

And then in the C# I can read a specific pin to get its state. Whit something like:

```
serialPort1.Read("pin44"); //and with that read I can see if its in HIGH or LOW.
```

Or

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
int pinNumber = serialPort1.**ReadPinNumber()**; //I would store the number of which pin is generating the data and do something with it.
}
```

I don't know if I was clear enough, but what I need is to constantly receive data from the arduino and know from which pin is coming from, so I can do something according to my needs.

I already succeded the first part. I can receive the data and do something about it. But when comes to multiple pins is the tricky part.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do this, but could you do something in Arduino like this:

```
int pin7val = 0;     // variable to store the read value

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(7, INPUT);      // sets the digital pin 7 as input
}

void loop()
{  
  pin7val = digitalRead(7);   // read the input pin 7
  Serial.write(pin7val + " Pin44");
}
```

Then in visual studio do something in a nutshell like

```
string Serial = serialPort1.ReadLine();

if (Serial contains "44")
{
int pin44val = Serial();
}
```

The C# syntax isn't probably all correct, but you get the idea.

Comment: I thought something like this... but i kinda feel its the wrong way to do it... i wanted something like: I read each one of the pins, like i build a dictionary, and update their states... it would be like: read pin 22 -> receives LOW -> store current state. read pin 23 -> receives HIGH -> store state... this from C# and not from arduino